# Problem saving xml to a TFS field

Tags: xml, tfs

I'm working with Linq to xml, and I save my xml in a standars text field in one ordanary SQL database.

Now to my problem: I want to be able to sync the things I save in my SQL text field with a field in TFS. The problem is when I save the xml which is a string, my TFS field removes all the xml tags, and when I query my tfs field again I get back the text in my xml without the xml tags, but with the `<body>` at the begining and `</body>` in the end?

I'm saving the text to the field in code using this:

```
workItem["Customer.CustomerXMLTalk"] = newXMLTalk.ToStringWithDeclaration();
```

What do I have to change with my TFS field inorder to be able to save the xml as a string without loosing my tags.

Thanks!

Comment: "TFS Field"? You mean a field in a TFS Work Item? How is the field defined? Please show us.

Comment: How do you save your work item? Maybe you have to encode the value first.

Comment: Hi! Yes I mean a field in a TFS Work Item. I'm not sure how the actual field is defined, but this is how I try to save a xml into a tfs field: workItem["Customer.CustomerXMLTalk"] = newXMLTalk.ToStringWithDeclaration();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try HTML Encoding the string before you save it.

```
workItem["Customer.CustomerXMLTalk"] = 
      System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(newXMLTalk.ToStringWithDeclaration());
```

Comment: Nice tips, seems to be working. Is there some nice method to convert it back to "correct" characters when reading it from TFS? Now my character < looks like &lt;

Comment: My bad, offcourse there is a decode option, System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode  , Thanks alot